# Assets in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've just started using codeigniter and wanted to include some external css in my view. This is my directory structure:

```
application
   ....
system
   ....
assets
    css
        style.css
```

I'm linking the file using this html code: (Used example.com as an example, lol)

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/assets/css/style.css"/>
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now, my problem is that it returns an 404 error. Say if you need more info.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the CI .htaccess rules some what restrictive having to add all different folders required.  I therefore use the following:

```
# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Give that a bash and see how you get on.