# In an external assets folder the best place to put libraries for CodeIgniter 2.x?

Tags: codeigniter

when I last used CodeIgniter it was version 1.x and I read an external assets folder for css, js, and images was the best way to handle things.  I wanted to know if that is the correct way to do things in 2.x.  I found this on SO but it didn't address it directly:

[Assets in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693182/assets-in-codeigniter)

The other SO entries were too old to address 2.x.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as they are both publicly accessible then there is no difference between

```
application
    ...
system
    ...
assets
    css
        style.css
    images
        image.png
```

and

```
application
    ...
system
    ...
css
    style.css
images
    image.png
```

Depending on your .htaccess file you may need to make a change but CodeIgniter doesn't require you to use any specific scheme for storing assets.